# Calculate Custom Rate Function in a Pandas Data Frame Using GroupBy

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Pandas data frame with the column `COLOR` containing categorical data and NaN values -

```
  ZIP    YEAR    COLOR
11111    1990        0   
11111    1990        1
11111    1990      NaN 
11111    1990        1
22222    2000        0
22222    2000      NaN
22222    2000      NaN
22222    2000        1
```

How do I aggregate the data by the `ZIP` and `YEAR` columns (`df.groupby(['ZIP', 'YEAR'])`) and calculate the categorical data as a rate such that the result resembles the data frame below? The rate should be calculated as the number of zeroes divided by the total number of records for each aggregate. For example, the rate for `df.groupby(['ZIP', 'YEAR'])` for `[11111, 1990]` is calculated by adding up the total number of zeroes (1) and dividing that number by the sum of the total number of zeroes and ones (3), resulting in 1/3 as 0.33.

```
  ZIP    YEAR    COLOR
11111    1990     0.33            
22222    2000     0.50
```

Answer (score 1):

First we convert your `0` to `1` and other way around.

Then we use `GroupBy.sum` and `GroupBy.count`:

```
df['COLOR'] = df['COLOR'].sub(1).abs()

grps = df.groupby(['ZIP', 'YEAR'])
dfn = grps.sum().div(grps.count()).reset_index()

     ZIP  YEAR     COLOR
0  11111  1990  0.333333
1  22222  2000  0.500000
```